# Ansible command execution error

Tags: bash, ansible

I have a bash script, which I execute on a node using Ansible.

```
- name : execute the script for uploading www files
  shell: /root/upload_www.sh
```

Part of the script is executing:

```
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $key user@$backupsrv "sudo rsync -ravzhe \"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $key\" /var/www/html user@$source:/var/www/"
```

That script executes very long time (about 3 hours, because there are rsync tasks with about 80gb of data and other logic) and the Ansible task finishes with an error message: `"Killed"` but the script
continues to execute and all tasks in that script do eventually finish successfully.

On the Ansible host after running the command `ansible-playbook www.yml` I get the following output:

```
# echo $?
137
```

How can I wait for my script to end properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your task an [asynchronous action](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_async.html) instead by adding the `async: "{{ max_wait_time }}"`option:

```
- name : execute the script for uploading www files
  shell: /root/upload_www.sh
  async: 10800 # max wait of 3 hours in seconds
  poll: 300 # check for completion every 300 seconds
```

However, I'd be wary of using the asynchronous action for such a long time period and whether you might be better off with a different approach altogether but it's difficult to suggest a better way of doing things without knowing the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The reason was in memory less:

    ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $key user@$backupsrv "sudo rsync -ravzhe \"ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $key\" /var/www/html user@$source:/var/www/" > /dev/null 2>&1

All output from the node was located in ansible host, there was many files, so linux killed that process. Thank you.